# Cannot remove labels gmail api

Tags: javascript, python, function, gmail-api, label

I am working on an app using the gmail api, and I cannot remove labels from messages, specifically the UNREAD label. Here is the code I am using:

```
function modifyMessage(userId, messageId, labelsToRemove, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.modify({
    'userId': 'me',
    'id': messageId,
    'removeLabelIds': labelsToRemove
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

I call this function with `modifyMessage('nothing', id, 'UNREAD', '');` I think that the lack of 'callback' is what might be stopping this from working properly, however I have no idea. The 'id' is my messageId. The docs I am using are [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#javascript). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation states](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#javascript), `removeLabelIds` has to be an array:

```
function modifyMessage(messageId, labelsToRemove, callback) {
  gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.modify({
    'userId': 'me',
    'id': messageId,
    'removeLabelIds': labelsToRemove
  }).execute(callback);
}

// modifyMessage('<message-id>', ['UNREAD'], callback);
```

Comment: For some reason this is still not working, my exact code is `function modifyMessage(messageId, labelsToRemove, callback) {
  gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.modify({
    'userId': 'me',
    'id': messageId,
    'removeLabelIds': labelsToRemove
  }).execute(callback);
}
function markAsRead(id){
  modifyMessage(id, ['UNREAD'], callback);
}` and I call it like this `markAsRead(this.id)` (this.id returns something like 'e15lxxxxxxxxxxxxx') Thanks for your help!

Comment: never mind, my issue was that I had not defined callback. Thanks agian